# How to load external jar in server startup in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE.
And with this application, I'm using oracle drive for DB transaction.
Now, The scenario is like this, I can't use maven dependency mapping for this, it has to load it from, some external location while starting up.
Thereofore, the Springboot jar, will not have it, it will load from some external folder, while starting.

So, my question is,
**How to do that?**

Comment: Just add it as classpath element. But why wouldn't you be able to package in the jar? Just add it to your maven repository or add a system dependency and let the plugin include it in your jar.

Comment: no my requirement is, i will not packaged jar, that should be available in some external location, and it has to load it while starting up

Comment: Then just add it with the `-cp` option of the java command. Although I would recommend against as you will forget to include it, location changes etc.

Comment: can u please post an answer with this -cp, like how to do that?

Comment: You could read that java documentation? `java -cp ojdbc.jar -jar your.jar`.

Comment: it doesn't work... i have tried that

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot doesn't use the classpath like that.
Use the [loader.path setting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) to specify a directory containing that external jar you want to load
by default it should look in a folder called lib/ inline with the spring boot jar you're running

```
├── lib
│   └── ojdbc.jar
└── my-spring-boot-executable.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

simplify， you can install Oracle jdbc driver in your local environment or private maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

java -cp demo.jar -Dloader.path=c:/lib/ -Dloader.main=yourServer org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.